# How to display hidden list items when a parent list is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a family tree which I'm working on, the code was gotten from [this codepen](https://codepen.io/Pestov/pen/BLpgm). Here's the markup

```
<div class="tree">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I make it that only the `Parent` will be displayed, and other links will appear when the `Parent` link is clicked?

For example, if I click on the `Parent`, then the two `Child` will be displayed. If I then click on the 'Child' at the left, the `GrandCHild` is will displayed, but if I click on the `Child` at the right, the `Grandchild` of the left 'Child' will be hidden, and so on.

Comment: what has been tried so far

Comment: I do not know any javascript or jquery.

Comment: @SamuelAsor Before asking others to do your job, please consider learning at least the basics of JavaScript.

Comment: I will, @HubertGrzeskowiak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hide {
            display: none;
        }

        .show {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("a").click(function () {
                $("a:contains('Child')").siblings("ul").removeClass();
                $("a:contains('Child')").siblings("ul").addClass("hide");
                var ul = $(this).siblings("ul");
                $(ul).toggleClass("hide", "show");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tree">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent</a>
                <ul class="hide">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Child</a>
                        <ul class="hide">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Child</a>
                        <ul class="hide">
                            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                                <ul class="hide">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey @Denis, I tried out your code, but it is not working properly. Can you create a `Pen`?

Comment: Just copy and paste the code EXACTLY the way I have it and it will work.If it doesn't inspect the browser console for errors

Comment: It is working, but not as I expected. I want to be able to hide the elements of a `Child` when the elements of the other `Child` is displayed. And so on.

Comment: Please have a look at my update.I've changed the code based on your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Hide your `li`'s by default:

```
.tree li {
  ...
  display: none;
}
```

Display the root node by adding a class (`active`):

```
.tree li.active {
  display: block;
}
```

On clicking a node, toggle the `active` class to any child nodes in the next `ul` element:

```
$('a').on('click',function() {
    // First remove added class incase this node has been activated previously
    $(this).next('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).next('ul').find('>li').addClass('active');
})
```

---

Working Demo:

```js
$('a').on('click',function(){ 
  // First remove added class incase this node has been activated previously
  $(this).next('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).next('ul').find('>li').addClass('active');
})
```

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  
  display: none;
}

.tree li.active {
  display: block;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}

/*Thats all. I hope you enjoyed it.
Thanks :)*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--
We will create a family tree using just CSS(3)
The markup will be simple nested lists
-->
<div class="tree">
 <ul>
  <li class="active">
   <a href="#">Parent</a>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Child</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Child</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
       <ul>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

[Updated CodePen version](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbppxd)

---

**Edit**

To hide siblings when a child is clicked you would have to traverse back up to the parent 'li' and remove the active class from any siblings:

```
$('a').on('click',function() {  
  // First remove added class incase this node has been activated previously 
  $(this).next('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');

  $(this).closest('li').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).next('ul').find('>li').addClass('active');
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKVVGx)

Comment: I appreciate your effort @Turnip. How about, since there are two `Child`s, I want to be able to hide a `Child`, when the other is displayed.

Comment: See update. You would have to modify your CSS to accommodate the hidden nodes.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Pen</a></li>
                <li>
          <a href="#">Shoes</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Black</li>
                        <li>Brown</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Categories</a>
            <ul>
                <li>Page</li>
                <li>Data</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu ul {display:none;}
```

Js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#menu li a").click(function(e) {

        var li = jQuery(this).parent('li');

                    if(!li.has("ul")) {
                        return;
                    }

                    li.children('ul').toggle();



            });
});
```

[check This working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sabirsafder/puLga1ka/8/)